# Download Xcode documentation sets manually

Tags: xcode, documentation

For reasons unknown to me, Xcode fails to download the documentation sets from the server.

Is there a way to download these documentation sets manually from a URL and then have Xcode's Core Reference Library unpack them?

**EDIT:**

Found what I was looking for:

http://learning2code.blogspot.com/2008/05/download-xcode-docsets-to-your-hard.html

Comment: Don't edit the question with an answer, just answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for:

http://learning2code.blogspot.com/2008/05/download-xcode-docsets-to-your-hard.html

Comment: That site isn't working for me. Can you add the key information here?

Answer (score 9):

For Xcode 7.0 and maybe newer versions you should follow these steps to download and install documentation sets manually:

1. At first you should find your proper item in the below link:
   https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex

For example the following:

```
<!-- START iOS 9 doc set -->
<dict>
  <key>fileSize</key>
  <integer>1065107366</integer>
  <key>identifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS</string>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>iOS 9.0 Documentation</string>
  <key>source</key>
  <string>https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20150916/031-34987-A.dmg</string>
  <key>userInfo</key>
  <dict>
    <key>ActivationPredicate</key>
    <string>$XCODE_VERSION &gt;= '7.0' &amp;&amp; $XCODE_VERSION &lt; '7.1'</string>
    <key>Category</key>
    <string>Documentation</string>
    <key>IconType</key>
    <string>IDEDownloadablesTypeDocSet</string>
    <key>InstallPrefix</key>
    <string>$(HOME)/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets</string>
    <key>InstalledIfAllReceiptsArePresentOrNewer</key>
    <dict>
      <key>com.apple.pkg.7.0.iOSDocset</key>
      <string>10.9.0.0.1.1442278660</string>
    </dict>
    <key>RequiresADCAuthentication</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Summary</key>
    <string>My description of content</string>
  </dict>
  <key>version</key>
  <string>90.9</string>
</dict>
<!-- END iOS 9 doc set -->
```

2. Download the file from `source` string. In our example: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20150916/031-34987-A.dmg
3. Rename the downloaded file using following structure:

`"identifier string" + "-" + "version string" + ".dmg"`

In our example:
`com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS-90.9.dmg`

4. Then place it to:
   `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/`

If there is no `Download` folder, create it.
I suggest you to remove all files with `.dvtdownloadableindex` extension (if any exists).

5. Go to `InstallPrefix` string folder and remove existence related docsets (if any exists).

In our example the folder is `$(HOME)/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets` which refers to `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets.` Then remove the `com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset` file from there.

(In some cases, `$(DEVELOPER)` refers to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`).

6. Open Xcode, go to preferences... . In the Download tab, simply click download arrow for the document. You find that the Xcode just pass the download progress and install the document.

Comment: That failed at the first step - follow your link.  The Source listed on everything is http://developer.apple.com/none.dmg, which takes me to a broken link page.  I thought maybe I needed to sign in with my Apple ID, but that did not alter the contents of the XML returned, still all sources are none.dmg.

Comment: I should add, when I put the URL you listed for iOS 9, that gave me a dmg file to download.  So that worked, as a single example.  But the first link which is supposed to give us the complete doc set list, all have bogus sources.

Comment: Check out all versions and all sources. Maybe you choose a wrong docsets. I think, it returns https://apple.com/none.dmg for some outdated docsets that doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Augmenting the blog post mentioned in the accepted answer here, since its comments are closed:

There's a separate feed for each OS release. You can follow the Snow Leopard documentation at http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.atom

One way to find these URLs is to click the little "i" info icon for each DocSet in Xcode's Preferences -> Documentation -> Documentation Sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to download the iPhone docs you may be using an account that has no access to the docs.

> Using Keychain Access, delete the 'connect.apple.com' entry, then attempt to download the docs and enter your iPhone-registered account info. -- Ronald Hayden, [Cocoabuilder Xcode Archive](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/xcode/2008/11/30/26055)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to download the Core Library.