# Download Xcode 4.2 documentation for offline install

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I've read a few posts on how to install the missing documentation on Xcode 4.2 by going into the documents manager and downloading it directly. [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131119/download-xcode-documentation-sets-manually) suggest me to look into the [rss feed](http://developer.apple.com/rss/adcdocsets.atom), but I get only the Mac OS Lion Core reference, I want the iOS reference as well.

That's very nice, but ***I can't connect to the internet from the Mac where I work***, no need to enter in details, nor can install Mac OS on the PC where I connect, so my question is pretty simple:

Where can I obtain the required files to install them into Xcode and how do I install them?

Any links or instructions would be useful.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT** To download the Xcode documentation I just need the actual URL where the files are located, can't download them using Xcode because the PC I have with internet has Windows.

**EDIT** Although the @Saurabh's answer didn't gave a 100% to what I wanted, if you check the image well, there is a field saying feed and there is where everybody having this issue should look.

**EDIT:** In order to complete the question and make life easier for those looking for the actual files, these are the links

- [Apple iOS Documentation V 9.0](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20150916/031-34987-A.dmg)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 8.3](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20150408/Xcode_6.3_iOS_Docset.dmg)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 8.1](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20141020/031-07735-A.dmg)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 8.0](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20140917/031-06020-A.dmg)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 7.1](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20140311/031-1467-A.dmg)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 7.0](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20131022/031-1318-A.dmg)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 6.1](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20130130/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.1.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 6.0](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20120919/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 5.1](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20120307/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_1.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 5.0](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20111012/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_0.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 4.2 (Xcode 4)](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20101122/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.Xcode4.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 4.2 (Xcode < 4?) No so sure on this one](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20101122/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 4.3](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20110309/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_3.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 4.3 (Another?)](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20110720/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_3.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 4.1](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20100908/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_1.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 4.1 (Xcode 4)](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20100908/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_1.iOSLibrary.Xcode4_0.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 4.0](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20100803/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_0.iOSLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 3.1](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/Oct2009/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3%5F1.iPhoneLibrary.xar)
- [Apple iOS Documentation V 2.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documents/iphone_os_2.2_reference_library/com.apple.adc.documentation.appleiphone2_2.iphonelibrary.xar)

Finally, as stated in this question yu can find the Mac OS Lion reference here:

[Mac OS Lion Core Reference](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20111012/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleLion.CoreReference.xar)

Comment: Xcode 3.2.6 (at least) and before include the doc set with the download. All known Xcode download links are listed at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-and-get-the-dmg-file

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here you are the steps:

Download the documentation from Xcode from any machine.

Go the download installation (See Figure Below)

Copy the "documentation set" files (it is actually packages with a lot of file so it is recommend to zip them).

Move them to the same location where you installed Xcode on the other machines

Restart Xcode.

Done.

How to download documentation file online - 
If you are connected to Internet you can download the documentation file. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads (this is the screen I attached). Here you will find iOS 4.3 Library in listing and and button on right "Install". Just Click the button "Install" for the items you want to download.

After documentation download you can see its path and copy the files to other systems.
Hope it clears your question completely.. if not please post in comments.

[image]

**Edited**

As I am still getting upvotes on this answer I thought its better to post some links to download new SDK's documentations.

iOS SDK 5.1 - https://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone5_1.atom

iOS SDK 6.0 - https://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone6.0.atom

Mac OS X 10.6 core library - https://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.atom

Mac OSX 10.8 - https://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.atom

Xcode 4.0+ developer library - https://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleXcode4_0.atom

Comment: Very nice, still the main point of the question is where do I download the documentation files from?

Comment: Like I said from the begining, I can't connect to the internet from Mac, so I need where to get the files (like a RSS feed), so I can download them from windows.

Comment: sorry you can't download documentation on windows system for iOS5. You can ask to a friend to download it on his mac and then you can copy the files to your offline mac

Comment: yes and no... your answer did came up handy and I've found the files... will make a blog post about it soon... :)

Comment: hello.. could someone tell me if I can install a c++ documentation in XCode? I wanna learn C++ and don't wanna google every time I need to check something..