# Download iOS SDK 7.0 documentation for offline install

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I've read some posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542614/download-xcode-4-2-documentation-for-offline-install) about doing this using older versions of the iOS SDK.

I can't connect to the internet from the Mac at my home, so i need the link to download the iOS SDK 7 docset and install it offline. I use a similar approach in the previous one [6.1](https://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone6.1.atom) and it works like charm.

Is there any link or way to follow for getting the offline documentation and install it offline in my xCode 5 ??

**EDIT:** I need the direct link to download it since i have not osx in the machine that have the internet conection.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I fired up Wireshark to inspect where Xcode itself downloads the documentation when doing it the normal/online way via the Downloads-tab in Xcode's Preferences:
[image]

So here are the various download links:

- [**`iOS 7 doc set`**](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20131022/031-1318-A.dmg)
- [**`iOS 8 library doc`**](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20140917/031-06020-A.dmg)
- [**`OS X 10.9 doc set`**](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20131022/031-1317-A.dmg)
- [**`Xcode 6 library doc`**](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20140917/031-07736-A.dmg)

Just open the image and execute the installer:
[image]

Comment: That's good for sure, the only problem is that my Mac doesn't have internet conection so i need a link to download the docset and install it offline. Thanks

Comment: oh sorry I missed the point that your Mac is already offline ;)

Comment: Can you post the link for iOS 8 please, I have a similar problem?

Comment: @ZeusAlexander: I updated the post with links to the iOS 8 and Xcode 6 library documentation

Comment: @Mobiletainment: Could you post the link for iOS 8.1 docs? I just installed XCode 6.1, and it won't let me download says the devimages.apple.com server certificate is invalid. But your links above do work for me. Thanks!

Comment: @stonemonk See mike's answer. Open this link https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex Find the section of iOS 8.1. Then you'll find the download link.

Comment: Does it actually work? I installed the pkg successfully, but xcode still uses internet resources instead of the local one (I'm using IOS 8.1 docset)

Comment: Indeed, I am having problems as well, doesn't work without internet. Is there any step by step installation guide? what is the correct installation directory to place all the files?

Answer (score 7):

I've had a similar problem very recently with downloading docsets for Xcode 5.1.1.

My job took me to a very remote place, where we use a 256kbps satellite link as our only Internet connection, and that is mainly used to transfer a substantial amount of scientific data back to our HQ, as well as for the VoIP phones. There's very little bandwidth left for any other purpose and even that is shared between thirteen people.

I can't, therefore, use the normal download mechanism from Xcode, as it would likely time out and/or fill the link completely.

What I can do instead, is to use rsync with bandwidth limit to pull files from a server at home. To do that, I had to find the URLs for the docsets.

It turns out, Xcode uses an XML file available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex), which contains a list of all docsets, along with the xcode versions that those docsets are available for. This seems to be refreshed every 24 hours. You can then parse (or manually look through) this file to grab your URLs as needed and download them with wget, curl or any other client. No need for Wireshark!

Comment: How did you even find that file?

Answer (score 1):

I would grab Dash (http://kapeli.com/dash).  It downloads any docset you get your hands on as well as iOS SDKs and makes them available anytime.  Dash is not free, but if you don't pay for it, there is a small and unobtrusive ad.  I think after using it for a while, you won't mind paying the small fee to support its ongoing development.

Comment: i use the mac in an offline enviroment so i can't do that. I edit the question a bit.

Comment: Also, as of the newest version of Dash, it asks you to download the iOS/OSX docsets through Xcode for Dash to use.

Comment: Actually just tried now the Dash. When you install the docset, go to the installation and find the installed packet. Or just search for the "docset" in finder. Later in Dash you can choose this packet and it will be available from within.