# Download iOS 7.1 simulator in XCode 6.2 for offline install

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717625/download-ios-sdk-7-0-documentation-for-offline-install) but for downloading the iOS docsets and install it offline.
My scenario is simple:
I can't connect to the internet from the Mac at my home, so i need the link to download the iOS 7.1 simulator and install it offline. XCode 6.2 install the latest 8.2 but i need the 7.1 one to test older apps. (I need the direct link to download it since i have not osx in the machine that have the internet connection)

Relating to the docsets there is this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex) where i can download the files and install it in an offline development machine.

So my question is where i download the 7.1 simulator to install it in an offline dev machine.

Comment: Hello Javier
Have u got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

So this is where you can download the Simulator in the newest Xcode.

[image]

Go to:

Applications –> Xcode –> show contents –> contents –> applications –> iOS Simulator

If you then copy it onto some USB then I guess you will be able to use it on the offline machine.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: See the last part of the first paragraph "i have not osx in the machine that have the internet connection", so there is no way that i can download it that way. I need a direct link.

Answer (score 0):

The file may be cached below ~/Library/Developer, but another option is to just rsync /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator to your other devices or create a tarball of the simruntime bundle below /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator for manual installation later.