# Xcode 5.1 documentation download temporary location?

Tags: xcode, download, crash, temporary-files

Xcode 5.1 crashed during the download of some documentation this week. The problem is, something must've got corrupted in the partial download and now and attempt to resume the download reliably crashes Xcode again. Does anyone know the location of the partial documentation download so I can wipe it and start from scratch?

Info would be most appreciated!

Thanks in advance

J

Comment: Yes, worth a try (although on poor network this week!). I guessing that the temporary location for docs isn't inside the application bundle, though.

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded doc set updates are installed in ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets.

You can get more information on this [apple Doc1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-documentation_preferences/SettingDocPreferencesHelp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010349-CH1-SW1), [apple Doc2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-documentation_preferences/DownloadingandInstallingXcodeComponents/DownloadingandInstallingXcodeComponents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010349-CH2-SW1)

You also can get more information on this link for manually download apple documentation

[documentation for offline install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542614/download-xcode-4-2-documentation-for-offline-install)

Answer (score 0):

Check ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode